# Dimensions changed cube (prism) is still a cube when UV unwrapped

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I've changed dimensions of a cube to make it a prism. Then unwrapped it for UV mapping, but it is still a cube in UV view when unwrapped.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to apply scale (object mode) before unwrapping (if you don't apply scale, you may see a quick message on the top of the screen)

Comment: It works, I didn't know I had to apply a transform, kind of not so intuitive, yet I guess there is a reason. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UV unwrap is here applied on an uniformly scaled object.

If the scale is non uniform (for instance X=1, Y=1, Z=2), the unwrap will be applied *on a non scaled version of the mesh*.

This can be seen if you stretch the information panel a bit (on top of this picture) :

[image]

So as a solution :

- Use <kbd>Ctrl + A</kbd>
- And select *scale*
- Then unwrap again

[image]

**Concerning the reason** (as you asked in the comments of your question), I presume this is due to the fact UVs are part of the mesh data and scale is relative to the object data. So this allow to have uniform UV for several objects sharing the same mesh data, but having different scales.